# Trying to solve a set of linear equations...

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I am trying to solve this set of linear equations:

$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 s_{12} & s_{12} & s_{13} \\
 s_{21} & s_{22} & s_{23} \\
 s_{31} & s_{32} & s_{33} \\
\end{array}
\right)\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 \lambda  & -\lambda  & 0 \\
 0 & \lambda +\mu  & -\lambda  \\
 0 & 0 & \mu  \\
\end{array}
\right)-\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 \lambda  & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & \lambda +\mu  & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & \mu  \\
\end{array}
\right)\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 s_{12} & s_{12} & s_{13} \\
 s_{21} & s_{22} & s_{23} \\
 s_{31} & s_{32} & s_{33} \\
\end{array}
\right) =\bf{0}$$

and I get no solution.

But, when I change it to

$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 s_{12} & s_{12} & s_{13} \\
 s_{21} & s_{22} & s_{23} \\
 s_{31} & s_{32} & s_{33} \\
\end{array}
\right) \left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 \lambda _1 & -\lambda _1 & 0 \\
 0 & \lambda _2+\mu _1 & -\lambda _2 \\
 0 & 0 & \mu _2 \\
\end{array}
\right)-\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 s_{12} & s_{12} & s_{13} \\
 s_{21} & s_{22} & s_{23} \\
 s_{31} & s_{32} & s_{33} \\
\end{array}
\right) \left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 \lambda _1 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & \lambda _2+\mu _1 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & \mu _2 \\
\end{array}
\right) = \bf{0}$$

I do get a set of solutions.

I can't seem to figure out why this happens. Any direction would be greatly appreciated.

For the second set, here's how I solved it. Just multiply the matrices out and we get...

$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 0 & s_{12} \left(-\lambda _1+\lambda _2+\mu _1\right)-s_{11} \lambda _1 & s_{13} \left(\mu _2-\lambda _1\right)-s_{12} \lambda _2 \\
 s_{21} \left(\lambda _1-\lambda _2-\mu _1\right) & -s_{21} \lambda _1 & -s_{22} \lambda _2-s_{23} \left(\lambda _2+\mu _1-\mu _2\right) \\
 s_{31} \left(\lambda _1-\mu _2\right) & s_{32} \left(\lambda _2+\mu _1-\mu _2\right)-s_{31} \lambda _1 & -s_{32} \lambda _2 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

and then solve this set of linear equations...

$$s_{12} \left(-\lambda _1+\lambda _2+\mu _1\right)-\lambda _1 s_{11}=0, \\s_{13} \left(\mu _2-\lambda _1\right)-\lambda _2 s_{12}=0,
s_{21} \left(\lambda _1-\lambda _2-\mu _1\right)=0,\\
\lambda _1 \left(-s_{21}\right)=0,\\
\lambda _2 \left(-s_{22}\right)-s_{23} \left(\lambda _2+\mu _1-\mu _2\right)=0,\\
s_{31} \left(\lambda _1-\mu _2\right)=0, \\
s_{32} \left(\lambda _2+\mu _1-\mu _2\right)-\lambda _1 s_{31}=0, \\
\lambda _2 \left(-s_{32}\right)=0, \\
s_{11}+s_{12}+s_{13}=1, \\
s_{21}+s_{22}+s_{23}=1 \\
s_{31}+s_{32}+s_{33}=1$$

To get:

$$s_{11} = -\frac{\left(\lambda _1-\lambda _2-\mu _1\right) \left(\lambda _1-\mu _2\right)}{\lambda _1 \mu _1-\lambda _2 \mu _2-\mu _2 \mu _1},s_{12} = \frac{\lambda _1 \left(\lambda _1-\mu _2\right)}{\lambda _1 \mu _1-\lambda _2 \mu _2-\mu _2 \mu _1},s_{13} = \frac{\lambda _1 \lambda _2}{-\lambda _1 \mu _1+\lambda _2 \mu _2+\mu _2 \mu _1},s_{21} = 0,s_{22} = \frac{\lambda _2}{\mu _1-\mu _2}+1,s_{23} = -\frac{\lambda _2}{\mu _1-\mu _2},s_{31} = 0,s_{32} = 0,s_{33} = 1$$

Comment: Are your unknowns $\lambda,\mu$ in the first set and $\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\mu_1,\mu_2$ in the second set? If so, why would you expect them to have the same solutions. The first set has two unknowns, the second has four unknowns.

Comment: @almagest No where in the question did I suggest they get the same set of answers. All I said is that the first set of equations elicit no solution, while the second set does.

Comment: Your resolution of the second system is quite wrong.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the solution to the second set of equations is correct...Why do you say it's incorrect? Also, this is the result I get from Wolfram

Answer (score 1):

There is no mystery. The two systems have no reason to be both solvable, they have nothing in common.

The first system has the form

$$S\Lambda-\Lambda'S=0$$ while the second is

$$S\Lambda-S\Lambda'=S(\Lambda-\Lambda')=0$$
where $\Lambda-\Lambda'$ has a single nonzero element (the solution is $s_{11}=s_{21}=s_{31}=0$ or $\lambda_1=0$).